# env variable giving a weird output --!

Tags: java, linux, env

I have the following code inside a .sh script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Set environment variables
ANT_HOME=/home/tools/ANT1.8.2
ANT_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
cd `dirname $0`/..
BASEDIR=`pwd`

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH JAVA_HOME ANT_HOME ANT_OPTS

echo
java -version
echo "JAVA_HOME: $JAVA_HOME"
echo "CLASSPATH: $CLASSPATH"
echo "ANT_HOME: $ANT_HOME"
echo
env
```

JAVA_HOME has already been set before running the script. I am getting the following output:

```
java: java: cannot execute [Exec format error]
JAVA_HOME: /path/to/jdk1.6_64bit
CLASSPATH:
ANT_HOME: /home/tools/ANT1.8.2

_=*32592*/bin/env
ANT_HOME=/home/tools/ANT1.8.2
ANT_OPTS=-Xmx512m
...so on
```

The machine is 64-bit. I do not understand why am I getting the java error. The weird part here is this:

```
_=*32592*/bin/env
```

It looks like I am getting the error due to this *32592* but I'm not able to figure out what it is??

Can someone please help me or give me some suggestions?

EDIT: Sorry, I am running this script on Linux machine itself, not AIX machine. The reason I am pointing JAVA_HOME to an aix version is because further operations are done after connecting to an AIX machine through this script.

Comment: What is the output of `file /path/to/jdk1.6_64bit/bin/java`?

Comment: `bash: /path/to/java1.6.sp8.64bit/bin/java: cannot execute binary file`. I have tried setting it to other updates of JDK like java1.6.sp16.64bit as well. But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: can you run /path/to/jdk1.6_64bit/bin/java -version from a shell directly? Please check whether it gives the same error.

Comment: Hi Zhao, you mean from the command line right? I did that (my comment above). It doesn't matter which shell I'm using, I'm still getting that error.